# Using three monitors with the ATI Radeon HD 5450

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I count 3 connectors on my ATI Radeon HD 5450:

- DVI connector
- HDMI connector
- VGA connector

I connected a monitor  via VGA, then got another TV screen by connecting HDMI and everything worked fine.

I recently acquired a monitor with DP and bought a DP to DVI converter to connect this, but it didn't work. I have tried:

- another DP to DVI and nothing converter
- another DVI cable
- restarting (which too many times I've done and nothing happens )

The only thing that remains to me to know is if the DP to DVI converter can work at all, which would be illogical to make them if not.

Comment: HD 5450 is a pretty low-end card... might simply not support 3 monitors

Answer (score 1):

On all HD 5xxx series video cards, three monitors are supported only if you have AMD Eyefinity, which also requires a Display Port... If the vendor of your card included an HDMI port instead of a Display Port, it will only support two monitors.

See this Anandtech review of the HD5450, and look towards the bottom, it is spelled out a little clearer.

http://www.anandtech.com/show/2931/2

Comment: Depends. The well used Sapphire 5450 has an active converter on board so you drive 3 monitors. I used it to run NetBSD with three 1920x1200 monitors.

Answer (score 0):

The HD5450 is very old, might not support EyeFinity. I would recromend just getting a slightly newer card, a r7, or even a r9 series. Please note that you can only run more than one monitor off of one card, so you cant crossfire cards, and use the display ports on both of the cards, only one. Nvidia's technology allows you to run multiple monitors off of different cards in sli.